# C# DataColumn Caption Case

Tags: c#, case-sensitive, case-insensitive, datacolumn

I found a strange behavior of the DataColumn.Caption property:

```
dataTable.Columns[name].Caption = "test";
dataTable.Columns[name].Caption = "TEST";
//Caption is still "test"
```

I checked the implementation of the Caption property, which contains the following String comparsion:

```
if (caption == null || String.Compare(caption, value, true, Locale) != 0) {
   caption = value;
```

As you can see, they ignore case. I just wonder, why they've implemented this behavior. Does anyone have a explanation for this?

As a solution I came up setting the caption to null before updating the name - which seems pretty ugly to me, but I see no other workaround for this.

Comment: A rose by any other name would smell as sweet. Similarly CB_DEV and cb_dev both refers to you.